# Unable to Update tile content

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I have created 4 tile template contents and updated the tile with these four templates when the application is launched.

Now I want to clear only one tile template from the application. I tried

```
TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication().Clear();
```

but this is clearing all the tile templates. How do I clear just one particular tile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to `Clear` a specific notification from the tile. The `Clear` method removes all notifications.

For expiring tile content, consider using the `ExpirationTime` property on the `TileNotification` class, or calling `Clear` followed by resending the notifications that are still valid.

- Further details are given at [point 9](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/apps/hh465439.aspx#optional__clear_your_tile_notification) in this [Microsoft article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/apps/hh465439.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This took me a while to figure out, so thought i would post my code for anyone looking for a quick answer.

```
private void ClearScheduledTileNotifications()
    {
        var notify = Notifications.TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication();

    // Clear the notifications. This wil stop the live tile stuff straight out, but it wont remove the items from the list.
        notify.Clear();

       // Get the list of notifications
        var list = notify.GetScheduledTileNotifications();
        // Loop through the list of notifications and remove them from the manager.
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            // NOTE: If you want the list to exist, you could change the expiration date here as recommended in the 
    // MS Article above. I am just removing. You could also search for specific criteria here, or use linq on the query above.
            Notifications.TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication().RemoveFromSchedule(item);
        }
    }
```